# Render ExtJs Controls in Ajax Response

Tags: ajax, extjs, calendar, request, textfield

I am trying to Load ExtJs Controls in Ext.Window() using Ajax but its doesnt load via ajax.

what I want is in ExtJs Calendar's New Event Window, I am making ajax call and in response I sending Html with ExtJs controls, but ExtJs Controls doesn't appears into this screen.
So How can I do this?

// My Ajax Request...

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
       name:"new-event",
        modal:true,
        autoTabs:true,
       shadow:true,
       width:680,
       id:'new-event',
       height:500,
       autoScroll:false,
       autoLoad:{
           url:'new'
       },
       title:"New Event"
    });
win.show();
```

// Response Html which I am sending in Response(Json Encoded)

```
<ext:TextField name="name" allowBlank="false" enablekeyevents="true">
   <prop:Actions>
      <ext:Action onevent="focus">
         <prop:Handler>
            getFocus("1");
         </prop:Handler>
      </ext:Action>
      <ext:Action onevent="blur">
         <prop:Handler>
            lostFocus("1");
         </prop:Handler>
      </ext:Action>
   </prop:Actions>
</ext:TextField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try enabling the scripts on your autoload?
Add the following line to your autoLoad code

```
autoLoad:{
    url:'new'
    // Here add the scripts enabling
    ,scripts: true
},
```